# UIButton highlight area extends way outside button

Tags: ios, uibutton, touch

When the user touches a UIButton, the highlight state should start. When he slides his finger outside of the button (still without lifting his finger), the button highlight is supposed to stop, and when he lifts his finger the button should not be triggered.

This behavior is exactly how iOS works, but I'm a little surprised about the effective area for which the highlight is still applied. For a small button, I have to move my finger several times the height of the button above or below the button before the highlight stops.

Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong? Is the highlight area supposed to be controlled by the framework or is it something I can set?

Comment: Do you put `UIButton` programmatically or by Interface Builder? If by code - please show us a sample

Comment: Both. Programatic vs IB doesn't seem to make a difference. Before writing this question, I created a blank project, added a UIButton via Interface Builder, and tested it. The highlight area is 5x the size of the button.

Comment: check whether you have autosize options in size inspector making UIButton stretch. Also try to override its frame with custom CGRectMake

Comment: The problem here is your use of the words "should" and "is supposed to". You mean "I expect." But what you expect is not necessarily how the framework works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behavior of a framework for any UIButton whether you select a property of "show High light on touch" or NOT for a button.

But there is little bit change in behavior when one use "info light" button. The selection area of "info light" button is slightly bigger than the size of its own.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up subclassing UIButton to get the desired behaviour. In this example I change the buttons background to show the user when they are going to trigger the button and when they are not.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch = touches.randomElement() else { return }

    let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self)

    if self.bounds.contains(touchPoint){

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }
    else{

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch = touches.randomElement() else { return }

    let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self)

    if self.bounds.contains(touchPoint){

        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
    else{

        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Interestingly if you code a UIAlertController the UIAlertAction buttons behave as you would expect: if a touch leaves the buttons bounds the highlight goes off. However for UIButton's the touchDragInside frame is a lot larger than the graphics frame. Others have suggested this is to allow for clumsy and/or 'fat' fingered users. The inconsistency between the two buttons is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDragOutside), for: . touchDragOutside)

@objc func touchDragOutside() {
    button.isHighlighted = true
}
```