# Unwanted Invisible detection area around UIButton when Highlighted

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uibutton

I am creating a "yes" and "no" UIButton in a universal device app in my viewDidLoad, like so:

```
   let yesUnpressedTexture = UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("yesButtonUnpressed.png"))!
    let yesPressedTexture = UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("yesButtonPressed.png"))!
    let buttonWidth = yesUnpressedTexture.size.width
    var yesButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    yesButton.setImage(yesUnpressedTexture, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    yesButton.setImage(yesPressedTexture, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    yesButton.frame = CGRect(x: device.x/2 - buttonWidth * worldScale - worldScale * 40, y:  device.y/2 - worldScale * 50, width: buttonWidth * worldScale, height: worldScale * 200)
    yesButton.addTarget(self, action: "deleteProgress:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.deleteView.addSubview(yesButton)

    let noUnpressedTexture = UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("noButtonUnpressed.png"))!
    let noPressedTexture = UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("noButtonPressed.png"))!
    var noButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    noButton.frame = CGRect(x: device.x/2 + worldScale * 40, y:  device.y/2 - worldScale * 50, width: buttonWidth * worldScale, height: worldScale * 200)
    noButton.setImage(noUnpressedTexture, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    noButton.setImage(noPressedTexture, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    noButton.addTarget(self, action: "cancelDelete:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.deleteView.addSubview(noButton)
```

They load and work correctly when testing on my iPad, however something strange happens when I test on any iPhone simulator. If you move your finger off of either button to cancel the touch, you have to move it significantly away from the button to do so. The respective button stays highlighted until the users finger is outside of the highlighted box I have shown in the photo.

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

I have tried setting the frame by using CGRectMake but there is no change.

Comment: Well we don't know the values of your parameters and analyzing it to make a guess  isn't always a fun thing to do. You could try view debugging to see the real buttons frames.

Comment: The real button frames are the actual size of the button. What values would you need to know?

Comment: Here is similar question stating that this is normal behavior, but I'm not sure I understand what that means. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595145/uibutton-highlight-area-extends-way-outside-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a feature of the OS and how touch events work. When you touch a `UIControl` (a `UIButton` in your case), the OS starts tracking your touch and movements and there's a predefined bounding rect around your control. Only after you move your finger outside this bound, the touch is considered to have exited the control - this is when the control loses it's focus (highlight) and also `TouchDragExit` and `TouchDragOutside` events are triggered.

If you want to change this, you can customize the tracking behavior by creating a `UIButton` subclass and overriding the `continueTrackingWithTouch(_:withEvent:)` method so you can end the tracking based on your own logic.

Comment: @jwade502 You are most welcome. Glad to hear it helped!